# Role assignment in Hive

Tags: security, hadoop, hive, authorization

I created a role(granted select access to Database) in Hive and applied to my user. Role has only select access to particular database but my user is able to access all other databases too.

Can someone please advise ? what I'm I missing here

Comment: do you have Ranger/Sentry for permission control?

Comment: Did you try creating permission from Ranger ?

Answer (score 1):

Hive does not support privileges on databases (it may depend to version), see [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization#SQLStandardBasedHiveAuthorization-Objects) :

> The privileges apply to table and views. The above privileges are not
>   supported on databases

And you may miss some configuration, see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization#SQLStandardBasedHiveAuthorization-Configuration).

Dont forget that Hive is not good enough to manage permissions, so I highly recommand to set up permissions in the [hdfs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html) layer not in Hive layer.